# Flatten nested json array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have the following JSON array:

```
[  
    { id: 1, name: "P1", groups: [ { id: 1.1, name: "G1.1" }, { id: 1.2, name:"G1.2" }]}, 
    { id: 2, name: "P2",  groups: [ { id: 2.1, name: "G2.1" }, { id: 2.2, name:"G2.2" }]} 
];
```

What is the most efficient method to convert it to the following structure using Javascript ES6?

```
[ 
    { id: 1, name: "P1", group_id: 1.1, group_name: "G1.1"},
    { id: 1, name: "P1", group_id: 1.2, group_name: "G1.2"},
    { id: 2, name: "P2", group_id: 1.1, group_name: "G2.1"},
    { id: 2, name: "P2", group_id: 1.1, group_name: "G2.2"},
]
```

Comment: what is wrong with the question? Please comment before voting down.

Comment: thanks @Luis for correcting the json

Comment: You should post your current attempt. If you aren't struggling with your own attempt, you aren't learning.

Comment: The question should be "How can I go from A to B", then It show how much effort you put in before asking such question :)

Comment: understand your concern, I know the basic foreach way but wanted to find if there is any inbuilt JS feature e.g. array.map / array.concat

Comment: You should always put what you've tried in the post, then you'll not have to comment on answers to add precision on what you want, and It show people that you actually put efforts before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `forEach`. 
Try the following:

```js
var arr=[  
    { id: 1, name: "P1", groups: [ { id: 1.1, name: "G1.1" }, { id: 1.2, name:"G1.2" }]}, 
    { id: 2, name: "P2",  groups: [ { id: 2.1, name: "G2.1" }, { id: 2.2, name:"G2.2" }]}
];


result = [];

arr.forEach((o)=>{
  o.groups.forEach((group)=>{
    result.push({
      "id" : o.id,
      "name" : o.name,
      "group_id" : group.id,
      "group_name" : group.name
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems.

1. If it is a json array, it should be like this.

---

```
var obj = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "P1",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 1.1,
        "name": "G1.1"
    }, {
        "id": 1.2,
        "name": "G1.2"
    }]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "P2",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 2.1,
        "name": "G2.1"
    }, {
        "id": 2.2,
        "name": "G2.2"
    }]
}
];
```

[you can validate json arrays using this link](https://jsonlint.com)

---

2. it little bit confused about your out put.That's why it made voting down.

After set an array, you can use `ForEach` for that.

```js
var obj = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "P1",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 1.1,
        "name": "G1.1"
    }, {
        "id": 1.2,
        "name": "G1.2"
    }]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "P2",
    "groups": [{
        "id": 2.1,
        "name": "G2.1"
    }, {
        "id": 2.2,
        "name": "G2.2"
    }]
}
];

res = [];

obj.forEach((e)=>{
  e.groups.forEach((group)=>{
    res.push({
      "id" : e.id,
      "name" : e.name,
      "group_id" : group.id,
      "group_name" : group.name
    });
  });
});

console.log(res);
```